# Bowtie2 gets stuck on alignment

Tags: sequence-alignment, fastq, bowtie2, cutadapt

I am aligning a fastq file as follows:

```
cutadapt -j 8 --quality-base 33 -l 20 \
     -o - /home/user/Documents/analyses/CRISPR-screens/screen3/D16.fq.gz | 
       ~/bowtie2-2.4.3-linux-x86_64/bowtie2 --no-hd -p 8 \
         -t -N 0 -x ~/moffat_tko3 - | 
           sed '/XS:/d' | cut -f3 | sort | uniq -c > ~/D16.guidecounts.txt
```

The expected output is similar to this:

```
head D16.guidecounts.txt 
329 A1BG_sgA1BG_1
669 A1BG_sgA1BG_2
65 A1BG_sgA1BG_3
397 A1BG_sgA1BG_4
100 A1CF_sgA1CF_1
731 A1CF_sgA1CF_2
396 A1CF_sgA1CF_3
536 A1CF_sgA1CF_4
427 A2ML1_sgA2ML1_1
978 A2ML1_sgA2ML1_2
```

However, there is no output from this command as `bowtie2` gets stuck. `cutadapt` works fine, but when that step is done, nothing happens for hours and it should only take a few minutes.
I have tried to take a subset of reads using `head` and `tail` as follows:

```
zcat D16.fq.gz | head -10000 | gzip -c > D16head.fq.gz
zcat D16.fq.gz | tail -10000 | gzip -c > D16tail.fq.gz
```

What confuses me is that these files don't freeze `bowtie2` and align well (> 90% alignment rates). Other files from the same sequencing run also align fine (NovaSeq SP flow cell 50 bp paired-end).

As far as I can tell the original fastq file looks fine:

```
zcat D16.fq.gz | head -12
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2101:1334:1172 1:N:0:GCCAAT
GCCCAGTGACCCTTTCACGGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAAAAT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,,FFFF
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2101:1606:1172 1:N:0:GCCAAT
AAAGTTCTATCTGTTGGGCGGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTCAAGT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFFFF:FFFFF:FFFFFFFFF,FFFF
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2101:1624:1172 1:N:0:GCCAAT
GCGACGGTTCATCTCCGCAAGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAAAAT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF:FFFFF:FFFFFFFF,FFFF


zcat D16.fq.gz | tail -12
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2278:30644:37059 1:N:0:GCCAAT
AGGTCATCCACTCTAGACCTGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAAAAT
+
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2278:30915:37059 1:N:0:GCCAAT
ATGAGGAGGGTGATGTTCCGGAGTTTTAGAGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAAA
+
FF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,FFFFFF:FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
@A00489:1088:HKN2TDRXY:2:2278:31638:37059 1:N:0:GCCAAT
GAGTGTGGTTGAGATCCCAAGTTTTAGGCTAGAAATAGCAAGTTAAAATA
+
FF:FF:F:FFFFFFFF,FFFFFF:FF::FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: I would suggest breaking up the piped commands and see if you get some errors when the commands are run separately